# High read performance database solution for storing simple data on Windows

Tags: database, performance, database-design, optimization, nosql

I though that I have a simple problem but I am struggling with it for the last few days. To make a long story short, here is a description of it:

- I have about 1 mil new records daily, each record consists of `record_name` (string, about 20 characters), `date`, `value`, the records are stored for about two years (~700mil records in database);
- most of the `record_names` are repeating every day;
- I need to have the ability to find the biggest value gains between the given dates, while preserving the ability to filter the results by wildcarding the `record_name`;
- the software running this needs to work on Windows XP.
- the most important thing is the execution time of each query.

So far I had tried MySQL database and Cassandra. While the MySQL has rather acceptable performance on Linux (by acceptable I mean that my not-so-high skills were sufficient to program something which works), it is very slow on Windows. The same thing is with Cassandra.

The data which are inserted to those databases are being imported from .csv files. First import takes about 5 mins to MySQL and 20 mins to Cassandra, the latter ones are taking more time. I suspect that maybe I mis-configured something, but to be honest - I didn't changed anything performance-related in the config files.

**The question is**: what is the best solution for working with this kind of data having performance in mind. The programming language is not important, almost any will work, as the queries are simple and implementing them in any of the languages will not take big amounts of time.

Thank you very much for interest in helping.

Comment: Couple of questions: how often are you going to be reading these tables? Also, the size of the database might be want to be considered (I am assuming you are going for SQL Express on Windows)?

Comment: @DarkWingCoder: the tables will be read by one user, two at most. The number of reads will be about ~200 - 300 per hour, but I would like to comfortable work with the results, without any need for waiting for them.

Comment: 1M new records daily is much, especially if you want to optimize for read by slowing down inserts. How are you adding them?

Comment: @ruslik: right now the records are being inserted by a simple java program, which parses the csv file and adds them in bulk of 100 records per one insert instruction using the either MySQL or Cassandra api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more detail, the problems posed seems to be fairly classic BI problems, where the solution is usually to prematerialize aggregate data, optimizing for query than insertion.

I'd ask a simple question 1st - do you need all the data in the DB?  I'd be tempted to just cook the different aggregates - all, record type etc. by time range e.g. by day or hour into a simpler, smaller rowsets using simple console apps to read rows, compute aggregates, then dump them into SQL for access by query.

While it's cool to select * across all rows - unless there's real business need, resist it.
With aggregate queries in mind, the No-SQL storage is a distraction, plain ol' files would be great for retaining your raw row storage, and tools like SQL are more than enough for the aggregate queries.

Comment: Thank you very much for having interest in help. My first solution was removal of redundant data, sadly, it appears that all of them are needed. The insertion time is not that important (data are bulk-inserted by a script at night), the problem is the read time and query execution speed, especially after few insertions. The end result is produced by something like: SELECT * FROM data WHERE record_name like '%-33X3-%' and date >= :from and data <= :to.

Comment: I'm not doubting that rows need to be counted - I'm advocating you aggregate to create for example a row like 'RecordName, Date, SumValue' - do this for each distinct recordname each day for example. Then insert that data into SQL.

Comment: *WHERE record_name like '%-33X3-%'* Expressions like that can't use an index. That's going to be a problem no matter what you do. You might be able to work around that if the record names are structurally similar, though.

Comment: Agreed CatCall, two things kick in 1) the number of rows to scan for match is reduced by orders of magnitude.  2) you can further normalize the normalize the data too, e.g. moving row type into a seperate table, such that you wildcard against the "types" table etc. the amount of data you scan is significantly reduced - the primary problem in the 1st place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the bottleneck first. Possible options: harddrive, database, driver, application code. You should also try postresql but honestly your choices of having something running reliably on Windows are slim. unless you go with Windows SQL Server (not free). Also Cassandra and MySql are VERY different and solve different problems.

Comment: I don't want to start any flame war but without any skills in super optimization of freely available solutions, the SQL Server is the best solution. As I had written, on Linux the query execution times are far better then running the query time on Windows. I am aware, that this may not be the OS fault but rather the ports of used technologies - still, I am stuck and need to came with something. I will try to do some simple profiling, it seems the obvious solution, didn't thought about it earlier as I only ran few simple queries, without using utilities like "EXPLAIN ..".

Comment: There's a broader problem here - its a design question of what data should be used to serve the query system - efficiently querying 1Bn row system is a non-trivial DB problem. Then we can start getting on the podium about an efficient system to service that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/gYaDfo). It's small, fast, scalable and very lightweight. It supports various APIs, including SQL, key-value pairs (NoSQL) and a Java Object persistence API. Generally speaking, Berkeley DB will outperform a general-purpose RDBMS because it's much smaller, more efficient and has much less overhead. Berkeley DB runs on Windows and is an excellent choice for developers who are looking for simple, easy to use, embedded data management.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express should fit your needs just fine.

Just aggregate the data- use SQL to get the values you need and store those in other tables.

Using this method, you can easily get around any performance difficulties and size limitations with SQL express.